# md-autocomplete md-require-match on lose focus

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I have an autocomplete control (Angular Material version 1.1.2) with md-require-match=true and a validation message

```
                                <md-autocomplete required
                              md-no-cache="true"
                              md-select-on-match = "true"
                              md-selected-item="vm.selectedItem"
                              md-search-text="vm.searchText"
                              md-items="country in vm.querySearch(vm.searchText)"
                              md-item-text="country.nm"
                              md-min-length="2"
                              md-selected-item-change="vm.updateOrgCountry(country.cd)"
                              md-require-match = "true"
                              md-input-name="countryField"
                              md-match-case-insensitive = "true"
                              md-floating-label="Country">
                              <md-item-template>
                                 <span md-highlight-text="vm.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{country.nm}}</span>
                              </md-item-template>
                              <md-not-found>
                                    No Countries matching "{{vm.searchText}}" were found.
                              </md-not-found>
                              <div ng-messages="orgForm.countryField.$error">
                                <div ng-message="required"></div>
                                <div ng-message="md-require-match">Country not found.</div>
                              </div>
                           </md-autocomplete>
```

When I first enter the control and start typing everything works as expected.  If I don't select an item from the list and then move away from the control I get the "Country not found" error message.

However if I go back to the control and start typing again I get the "Country not found" error message after every key press until I select something from the list.  I don't want this behaviour as the user should be seeing an error while still entering data.

Is there a way to configure the autocomplete control to only validate for a match as the control loses focus?